# What is the file size limit? (NodeMCU, Esplorer)

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, esplorer

I recently tried to host a little web interface from my ESP8266. But something kept failing until I realized that a bigger file (around 10kb) was corrupt. Well, not really corrupt, but simply incomplete. And no matter how I changed it, the file was always cut off after a certain amount of characters.

My compiled NodeMCU firmware is about 649kb in size, so there should easily be enough space. I mean my board has at least 4MB of storage (32m), so that should be plenty to store my lua, html and css files!

I used Esplorer to upload the files btw.
So what exactly is the limit here?
Is it a memory issue? A flash storage issue? An issue related to Esplorer?

Is it somehow possible to get bigger files onto my board?

edit:
I should mention that uploading the init.lua file always worked even if it was around 10kb. Maybe the uploading mechanism is different for the init.lua file?

Comment: Have you tried a different upload tool e.g. https://github.com/andidittrich/NodeMCU-Tool?

Comment: No, I haven't .

Comment: I tried that now and it solved the problem. So I assume it's a bug/limitation in ESplorer. You should put this into an actual answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's the long form of my comment above. My best guess is (was) that this be an issue with ESPlorer. Whenever I look at its source code I'm actually surprized how well it *usually* works.

At https://frightanic.com/iot/tools-ides-nodemcu/ I compiled a list of tools and IDEs for NodeMCU. I suggest you pick a different uploader and try again. The [NodeMCU-Tool](https://github.com/andidittrich/NodeMCU-Tool) for example is solid and it's definitely a lot better maintained than ESPlorer is.